# How to sort wallets in the Daedalus wallet sidebar

Tags: daedalus

Is there a way to customize the order of wallets in the sidebar of the Daedalus wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Daedalus automatically sorts wallets by their names. The only way to set the needed alphabetical order of your wallets in the sidebar is to rename each wallet accordingly.

To do this, go to the `More` tab.

[image]